# Rest - search for a resource using sensitive data (users and passwords for instance)

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-passport

When it comes to searching and filtering in Restful APIs, GET seems to always be the go-to HTTP verb because of it's advantages (caching, URL sharing, etc). But what if I wanted to retrieve a resource using sensitive data? Specifically, I want to pass credentials (username/email and password) to an endpoint and have it tell me if it matches a resource or not, simulating a typical login authentication system. Is it as simple as doing a POST request with such credentials to an endpoint that returns a matching resource? Do I create a RPC type of call and just return true/false? Is this even  logical and/or safe to do?

I tried looking up such a scenario but a lot of sites and comments only talk about actual API authentication. I already have my API locked behind OAuth and use the Client Credentials grant because user context isn't needed (I use PHP + laravel + passport to build my API and handle OAuth 2)

A bit more background on why I want to do this - this API is more of a general purpose API that returns data needed by a bunch of other systems we have set up. These existing/legacy systems all have their own databases but need to interface with the database this API exposes data for. They currently talk to this database by making actual calls to it, plus making a bunch of cross database joins too when needed. This makes it hard to test and introduces a lot of code duplication between assets so we decided that the most logical step to do is have a common API for them to work with instead. The only problem is authentication tables exist in the database used by the API, and these legacy systems (with their login forms) authenticate directly with this database. I basically would like to update all login calls and have them pull the right user instead via the API instead of doing cross database calls.

Comment: So it's 2 step. 1.) The client must have an oAuth token, and then 2.) the client must have a user/password for the legacy system. Correct? I see no *real* problem with this. In dealing with Legacy systems, just *do what works* and get it rolled out. You can always go back and change it later.

Comment: Actually, the API client has nothing to do with the actual user using a legacy system. The API client on a legacy system just connects to my API using an access token and this API has endpoints that can pull a bunch of needed resources. User accounts being one such resource. These accounts are what these legacy systems use for logging in though, so I need a way to simulate logging in by looking if a specific account resource matches what a user enters as username/password inside a legacy system (and set the appropriate sessions/cookies with the matching resource's data)

Comment: As @Ohgodwhy mentioned, here you can really just do "what works". In your case, since you're needing to send sensitive information in order to retrieve sensitive information, I see no problem with POSTing over HTTPS and returning the data from that. It's not textbook REST, but it will get the job done.